# create fixed size string in a struct in C#?

Tags: c#

I m a newbie in C#.I want to create a struct in C# which consist of string variable of fixed size. example DistributorId of size [20]. What is the exact way of giving the string a fixed size.

```
public struct DistributorEmail
{
    public String DistributorId;
    public String EmailId;       

}
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I am creating a webservice which return a structure. This web service is consumed by a Tool called as Sybase unwired platform to create abstract object(called MBO or mobile business object). However when I create an a variable of the type string, the variable created in Sybase unwired platform gives a warning saying undefined length of variable. In order to correct this I will have to define the length of the the variables used in my struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx), preallocated buffers, `String` is not the correct datatype.

This type of usage would only make sense in an interop context though, otherwise you should stick to `String`s.

You will also need to compile your assembly with `allow unsafe code`.

```
unsafe public struct DistributorEmail
{
    public fixed char DistributorId[20];
    public fixed char EmailID[20];

    public DistributorEmail(string dId)
    {
        fixed (char* distId = DistributorId)
        {
            char[] chars = dId.ToCharArray();
            Marshal.Copy(chars, 0, new IntPtr(distId), chars.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

If for some reason you are in need of fixed size buffers, but not in an interop context, you can use the same struct but without `unsafe` and `fixed`. You will then need to allocate the buffers yourself.

Another important point to keep in mind, is that in .NET, `sizeof(char) != sizeof(byte)`. A `char` is at the very least 2 bytes, even if it is encoded in ANSI.

Comment: If i use char datatype how do i assign value to it. Current I am using  


distributoremail.DistributorId = ((int)r["DistributorId"]).ToString();

Comment: @user2841448 I've added a usage example in the constructor. Assignment isn't required to happen in the constructor of course.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a fixed length, you can always use a `char[]` instead of a string. It's easy to convert to/from, if you also need string manipulation.

```
string s = "Hello, world";
char[] ca = s.ToCharArray();
string s1 = new string(ca);
```

Note that, aside from some special COM interop scenarios, you can always just use strings, and let the framework worry about sizes and storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new fixed length string by specifying the length when you create it.

```
string(char c, int count)
```

This code will create a new string of 40 characters in length, filled with the space character.

```
string newString = new string(' ', 40);
```

Comment: Would vote down, but can't.  This would still create a variable length string.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char-system-int32)

Answer (score -1):

As string extension, covers source string longer and shorter thand fixed:

```
public static string ToFixedLength(this string inStr, int length)
{
    if (inStr.Length == length)
        return inStr;
    if(inStr.Length > length)
        return inStr.Substring(0, length);

    var blanks = Enumerable.Range(1, length - inStr.Length).Select(v => " ").Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}{b}");
    return $"{inStr}{blanks}";
}
```